# encode-decode base64 string AngularJS1 TypeScript?

Tags: angularjs, encoding, typescript, base64, decoding

I am using Angular1 with TypeScript. I have a simple question.

Is there any way to encode-decode a string in base64 with the environment, I use.?

I have searched a lot, I could find [this](https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64). But I am not sure whether it is available with the Type-definition.

Comment: It doesn't matter that there is no tsd file. You can still use the libary. Either declare it as "any", or create your own simple definition.

Comment: Thnx for the comment. Sorry I dont get you. can you tell me how can I use that as a service inside typescript? preferably as an answer :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So following the example from https://github.com/ninjatronic/angular-base64 but with a bit of TS decoration:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', ['base64'])
    .controller('myController', [

        '$base64', '$scope', 
        function($base64: any, $scope : ng.IScope) {

            $scope.encoded = $base64.encode('a string');
            $scope.decoded = $base64.decode('YSBzdHJpbmc=');
    }]);
```

So all I've done here is said that the $base64 parameter is "any", this allows you to use regular JS against it without TS complaining. You won't get intellisense / type checking against it, but that doesn't matter. As I said in the comment if you do want to define your own interface against it you could. i.e

```
interface Base64Encode {
    encode: (source: string) => string;  
    decode: (encoded: string) => string;
}
```

Comment: So, I should be able include your 1st code-snippet inside a .ts file right??

Comment: Well this is an example, you will need to fit it into your code, but my point is that it doesn't matter what is injected if you give it a type of any, then TS won't get in the way.

Comment: Yes, I understood. Actually I didn't ask that whether I can copy and paste. :)) .  I'll update soon after I tried out. :))